# Solder a push button directly to Raspberry Pi Zero GPIO

Tags: raspberry-pi, soldering, button

I would like to solder a push button directly to the Raspberry Pi Zero's 40 GPIO row (without the header). I am looking for instructions on how to do it and also possibly for a suitable button type/part that will nicely fit to Pi's GPIO hole dimensions. The button has to betall enough so that it could be enclosed in a 3D printed case and still be accessible with a finger from outside the case.

[This 10 mm tall Omron type B3F](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8605) is nice but I think the dimensions of its "legs" are not very compatible with the GPIO row.

Alternatively, I could use Zero WH with header, and solder the button directly to the header. But still a suitable button part is needed.

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: Yes I am looking for a suitable push button part. That is my question.

Comment: Questions which seek part recommendations to purchase are off-topic as a matter of site policy.  Additionally, you haven't even specified how the button needs to fit - ie, the dimensions between the signals it needs to bridge and the adjacent copper it needs to avoid.  And what you propose is mechanically unreliable anyway.  You might consider getting some PCB stock and *carving* a footprint pattern in that, gluing or foam taping it to the pi board, and using small hookup wire to connect.

Comment: `I am looking for a suitable push button part` ... that is not a question, it is a statement that describes what you are doing .... `where can I buy a switch?` is a question ........ i repeat ... what is your question?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately most 4-pin tactile switches have pitch different from 2.54mm. Furthermore, they have contacts paired internally, so even if you find switch with suitable pitch (there are few available) you'd have to sacrifice pins 37, 38 too.

I'd suggest looking for 2-pin switches, something like Panasonic EVQ-2 series, with 5mm pitch and long pins, which would work just as fine as long button for your purpose.

[image]